# Create intersection of lines and circle using HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, css-shapes

I need a pointer on a world map as shown in below image:

[image]

I was able to create a circle using HTML/CSS and here is the one I created:

```
.circle {
border-radius: 50%/50%; 
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: black;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/sreeram62/8QRAJ/

Now I need 2 lines intersected along with image as shown in above image. Is it possible using html/css?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the pseudoelements `:after` and `:before` like in **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8QRAJ/1/)**

This is fully supported by all major browsers (IE9+) as shown [here](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent)

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%/50%; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
}
.circle:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -125px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.circle:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -125px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```